# how do you make the number of encoder hidden units and decoder hidden units equal in Siraj Raval's seq2seq tutorial

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am using a seq2seq model that was created by Siraj Raval but am having issues with the number of encoder hidden units and decoder hidden units.

In Siraj's TensorFlow seq2seq tutorial on Github (link: https://github.com/llSourcell/seq2seq_model_live/blob/master/2-seq2seq-advanced.ipynb), the number of decoder hidden units is twice the number of encoder hidden units. In the video that accompanies this notebook (link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ElmBrKyMXxs), Siraj says that this is because he wants the model to actually have to learn since the labels are the same as their corresponding inputs. For my problem, I want the number of encoder hidden units to be the same as the number of decoder hidden units. When I try to set the number equal to each other, I get the following error message:

`ValueError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 220 and 120 for 'rnn/while/lstm_cell/MatMul' (op: 'MatMul') with input shapes: [?,220], [120,400].`

This is raised from the line `decoder_outputs_ta, decoder_final_state, _ = tf.nn.raw_rnn(decoder_cell, loop_fn)`

My code is a bit different from Siraj's code, but I didn't change anything that had to do with how the model worked, just how it got the data and the size. My model has a vocabulary size of 30 and an input embedding size of 20. I have 100 encoder hidden units, and therefore (I think) currently have 200 decoder hidden units. How would I set the encoder hidden units and decoder hidden units to be equal? Thanks!

Comment: Your Matrix dimensions are wrong, in your error, `[?,220], [120,400].` you can see that 220 is not equal to 120, which is required in matrix multiplication, that dimensions match, to find out exactly what is wrong, I will need your code as well, put it on github and put the link here, I will look at it in the weekend and raise a pull request if I find something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the code from the Github repo, you are getting the dimension mismatch because for the encoder he uses the `https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/bidirectional_dynamic_rnn`. Hence, the cell state that is being passed to the decoder has both the cell states from the `cell_fw` and `cell_bw` concatenated together. That makes the cell state size of the encoder to be `[batch_size, 2 * encoder_hidden_units]`. Now, because the cell state size of both the encoder and the decoder have to be the same in order to set the initial state of the decoder to the final state of the encoder, the `encoder_hidden_units` have to be twice the size of `decoder_hidden_units`.

Comment: So it's not a problem that they are not the same size, that's just how it has to work for it to be bidirectional?

Comment: If the encoder is a bidirectional recurrent neural network, the cell state size of the decoder has to be twice the size of the encoder, so that when you pass the last cell state of the encoder to the decoder they will have the cell state size.